# CSS animation not working on firefox ... vector display not working on IE11

Tags: html, css-animations, vector-graphics

Here is the website. Scroll down to see the animation.

http://fics.deremoe.com

If you view it on Chrome, it works as intended. But when I view it on IE11, the vector image size is wrong. Also, in the Firefox, the height animation doesn't work.

here is the animation keyframes: These are in LESS in case you didn't know.

```
@header-height          : 10em;
@header-height-shrink   : @header-height/2;

@-webkit-keyframes animeHeaderBGShow {
    from{
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:100;
    }
}


@keyframes animeHeaderBGShow {
    from{
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:100;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes animeHeaderBGHide {
    from{
        opacity:100;
    }
    to {
        opacity:0;
    }
}

@keyframes animeHeaderBGHide {
    from{
        opacity:100;
    }
    to {
        opacity:0;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes animeHeaderShrink{
    from{
        height:@header-height;
    }
    to {
        height:@header-height-shrink;
    }
}

@keyframes animeHeaderShrink{
    from{
        height:@header-height;
    }
    to {
        height:@header-height-shrink;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes animeHeaderExpand{
    from{         
        height:@header-height-shrink;
    }
    to {
        height:@header-height;
    }
}

@keyframes animeHeaderExpand{
    from{         
        height:@header-height-shrink;
    }
    to {
        height:@header-height;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use browser specific CSS like this:

```
/************** I E ***********************/
     @-ms-keyframes animeHeaderBGShow {}
/************** F I R E F O X ***********************/
     @-moz-keyframes animeHeaderBGShow {}
/************** C H R O M E & SAFARI***********************/
     @-webkit-keyframes animeHeaderBGShow {}
/************** DEFAULT CLASS***********************/
     @keyframes animeHeaderBGShow {}
```